# Нелинейная регрессия методом Гаусса-Ньютона

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, регрессия

Требуется реализовать нелинейную регрессию облака точек круглого сечения.

Есть облако точек в 3d круглого сечения, требуется построить нелинейную регрессию и найти на облаке точек дефекты формы.

Подскажите, в какую сторону искать решение и есть ли примеры реализаций нелинейной регрессии?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, что приходит на ум для построения нелинейных регрессионных моделей это:

- [SVR](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html) (с [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function) и [полиномиальным](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel) ядрами)
- [RandomForestRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) основанный на лесе/ансамбле решающих деревьев и другие более продвинутые ансамбли основанные на решающих деревьях - такие как: [LightGBM](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-Intro.html) и [CatBoost](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/python_tutorial.ipynb)
- нейронные сети с линейным выходным слоем (нейронную сеть никак нельзя назвать линейной регрессией, даже несмотря на линейность выходного слоя)

PS примеры использования SVR и RandomForestRegressor можно найти по ссылкам выше

Comment: Я бы добавил, что `SVM` (и в частности `SVR`) на практике очень медленная штука в случае большого кол-ва данных. Ну и что при использовании сложных моделей обязательно нужно бороться с переобучением, например, используя кросс-валидацию. )

Comment: @CrazyElf, вопрос был «в какую сторону копать».  Если подробнее говорить о каждом алгоритме то тут можно целую книгу написать. ;)